# Is there an optimal way to use incinerators?

Tags: two-point-hospital

In Two-Point Hospital's "Close Encounters" DLC, there is a new type of bin called the "incinerator". It has the side-effect of putting off heat, so I thought to use them to solve both waste disposal and heating problems simultaneously on a cold map.

However, I found there are some drawbacks to this:

- Contrary to what its name implies, the incinerator doesn't destroy garbage so it still fills up and has to be emptied by a janitor.
- While it puts off heat, the amount of heat is directly proportional to how full it is. When empty, it puts off about the same amount of heat as a small radiator; when full it puts out none.
- Patients cannot vomit into incinerators, so they still require regular bins or else they'll go on the floor.

My main concern is with the heat aspect, since temperature is something of a balancing act. If I heat a room/space normally, and then place incinerators, everyone will complain about being too hot when the incinerators are empty/close to empty. If I don't heat the area adequately and use the incinerator's ambient heat to make up the difference, everyone will complain when they fill up and stop putting out as much heat.

Is there an optimal strategy for incinerators or do the trade-offs between temperature and capacity make them generally unusable for this reason?

[image: An incinerator located in a seating area]